# How can I make this Macro Recording apply to entire sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code:

```
Sub Macro11()

Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Load Book'!R[7]C[-1]"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Calculate
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Range("B8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Range("C8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("C5:C8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Range("B9").Select
Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Load Book'!R[8]C[-1]"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Calculate
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Range("C9").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("B10").Select
Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Load Book'!R[9]C[-1]"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Calculate
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("C10").Select
Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("B11").Select
Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("B1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Load Book'!R[10]C[-1]"
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Calculate
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Max Amps").Select
Range("B7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Load Book").Select
Range("C11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

I know it's very long and messy but it's done through Macro recording since I'm new to VBA. I have about 50-60 rows that I need to do this for but I feel like theres an easier way to automate this...with a for loop somehow. How can I implement this code with a loop instead of a recording for each iteration? The code shown above shows 4 iterations. R[7] through R[10]

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's very messy and hard to follow.
I *think* you're trying to do this:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Load Book")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max Amps")
        For lCounter = 7 To 10

            'Update the formula in cell B1 to the row indicated by lCounter.
            .Cells(1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "='Load Book'!R" & lCounter & "C1"

            'Copy the value from cells B6 and B7 to cells B8 and C8 on 'Load Book'.
            wrkSht.Cells(8, 2) = .Cells(6, 2)
            wrkSht.Cells(8, 3) = .Cells(7, 2)

        Next lCounter
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Each iteration pastes to different cells. Like for examlpe first iteration uses value from let's say Row 1 Column 1 of Load Book sheet and pastes that in Max amps B2. After it calculates the sheet, the value from Max Amps sheet cell B8 and B9 are pasted next to the initial copied value from Row1 Column 1, so Row 1 Column 2 and Column 3

Comment: Oops I mean't B6 and B7 need to be pasted into B8 and C8. But the row changes with each r1c1 that occur. For example, R[7]C[-1] gets copied into Max Amps cell B2. Then Calculate sheet. Then Max Amps Cell B6 and B7 get pasted into Load Book Cell B8 and C8 respectively. This same process has to happen agani for R[8]C[-1] and the results from max Amps get pasted into B9 C9. The way it is i think it only posts it to b8 c8

Comment: So, 7 rows down from the active cell and 1 column to the left (`R[7]C[-1]`) gets copied into cell `B2` and `B1` is the active cell in your code - so that's looking at cell `A8`?  If you want it to look at row 7, column 1 use `R7C1`, the square brackets make it a relative reference.  Not exactly sure what you're after, but maybe you can update the paste cells using the `lCounter` variable - `wrkSht.Cells(8,2) = .Cells(lCounter,2)` for example